# Change Price on CMS page based on currency selected

Tags: cms, currency

Can someone tell me in a multi-currency store, lets say on CMS page I want to write "Today's Deal XYZ product in USD 100. Now I want this "USD 100" to change based on store currency selected. How can i achieve this on a CMS page? Is it also possible to do this on static block?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can include in your cms page a block rendered by a template:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="path/to/file.phtml"}}
```

And in the file `path/to/file.phtml` you can add what ever you want. Here is an example:

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode() == 'EUR') : ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('Prices from 100 E')?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('Prices from 100 $')?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to recalculate shipping costs on a CMS page based on the chosen currency. And while Mariu's solution works, I prefer to keep my content in the CMS, instead of an external template. So I wrapped the currency strings and symbols in  tags and wrote a jQuery function, that replaces these strings on page load:

This is the **HTML Code in my CMS page**:

```
<span class="currency-symbol">$ </span><span class="currency-calculate">15.00</span></td>
```

And this is the **jQuery Function**, which I added in *app/design/frontend/default/{mytemplate}/template/cms/content_heading.phtml* (so it would only get loaded in CMS pages), but if it should always get loaded, you could add it to: */app/design/frontend/default/{mytemplate}/template/page/html/head.phtml*

```
<? //define PHP variables
$currency_rate = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyRate();
$currency_code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
$currency_symbol_mage = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();

//replace currency symbol, if there is a currency symbol - otherwise use the currency code:
if( $currency_symbol_mage == "") {
$currency_symbol = $currency_code." ";
} else {
$currency_symbol = $currency_symbol_mage;
}
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //replace currency symbols
  jQuery('.currency-symbol').text('<?=$currency_symbol;?>');

  //recalculate + replace price in each .currency-calculate occurrence
  jQuery('.currency-calculate').each(function() {
    original_price = parseFloat(jQuery(this).text());
    currency_rate = parseFloat(<?=$currency_rate;?>);
    new_price = (original_price * <?=$currency_rate;?>).toFixed(2);
    jQuery(this).text(new_price);
    //somehow my function got triggered twice, so removing the class is a fix to make sure this doesn't happen:
    jQuery(this).removeClass('currency-calculate');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the trick works great at CMS page level but if I try to place the code in the HEAD (I need it in every page) it doesn't work.

The function is working but it doesn't change the text in the  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //replace currency symbols
  jQuery('.currency-symbol').text('AU$');

  //recalculate + replace price in each .currency-calculate occurrence
  jQuery('.currency-calculate').each(function() {
    original_price = parseFloat(jQuery(this).text());
    currency_rate = parseFloat(1.708100000000);
    new_price = (original_price * 1.708100000000).toFixed(2);
    jQuery(this).text(new_price);
    //somehow my function got triggered twice, so removing the class is a fix to make sure this doesn't happen:
    jQuery(this).removeClass('currency-calculate');
    });
});

</script>
```

and then in the html stays at it is...

Any suggestion?